# Python - One-hot-encode to single column

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I'm almost **zero** experienced with python but I'm trying to learn it. I have a Pandas dataframe which came with some dummies. I want to convert them back to a single column but I simply can't figure out a way to that. Is there any way to that?

I have this:

```
ID   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4
231    1     0     0    0
220    0     1     0    0
303    0     0     1    0
324    0     0     0    1
```

I need to transform to it:

```
ID   var  
231    1   
220    2   
303    3    
324    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these really are one-hot-encodings, use `np.argmax` along the first axis:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID' : df['ID'], 'var' : df.iloc[:, 1:].values.argmax(axis=1) + 1})

    ID  var
0  231    1
1  220    2
2  303    3
3  324    4
```

However, if "ID" is a part of the index, use this instead:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID' : df.index, 'var' : df.values.argmax(axis=1)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something new `wide_to_long`

```
s=pd.wide_to_long(df,['var'],i='ID',j='Var',sep='_')
s[s['var']==1].reset_index().drop('var',1)
Out[593]: 
    ID Var
0  231   1
1  220   2
2  303   3
3  324   4
```

Comment: I liked this answer but it's not working here. A have a variable without a separator so I just applied your code without the `sep` argument.

And I got this error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2), indices imply (2, 66899)`

Comment: @Rods2292 If the answer does not solve your problem, then please ask your question in such a way that a solution would naturally need to overcome it to be acceptable. Sound good? Or otherwise, please be fair and test out all the solutions before deciding what to settle on.